# C-String implementation in C++ outputs incorrectly

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, c-strings, string-concatenation

I was recently working on a problem teaching new users of C++, which I myself am, how to use cstrings and the different implementations of them compared to the imported string object in C++. As I was working on the problem, I came across an error where, despite initializing the size of the cstring to an appropriate length for the operations that were being done, the cstring was being outputted strangely.

When I would go to print out the cstring using cout, it would print some of the cstring correctly, but oftentimes the first several characters were random characters that had nothing to do with the operations being done to the cstring. However, I found a way to definitively prevent those characters from being printed; however, I am curious as to why this works as well as what the issue is here.

I found that adding `cout << "";` on its own line prior to printing the cstring resolved the issue of the random characters being outputted when printing the cstring. However, this seems like only a temporary fix and I am looking to find a more educated approach to solving this issue.

Below I have included the code that was causing the errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> words = {"Hello,", "and", "welcome", "to", "the", "world", "of", "C++!"};
    
    // Calculate the total number of characters in the words vector 
    // (including an additional character for space)
    int length = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        length += words.at(i).length() + 1;
    }
    
    cout << ""; // Removing this line of code will cause the output to do strange things
    
    // Initialize the cstring to be of size length
    char cstring[length];
    // Build the cstring using cstring library functions
    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        strcat(cstring, (words.at(i) + " ").c_str());
    }
    
    // Null-terminate the cstring
    cstring[length-1] = '\0';
    
    // Output the cstring
    cout << cstring << " " << strlen(cstring) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

If the line of code containing `cout << "";` is removed, the output looks something like this, with a random amount and random set of characters at the beginning of the output each time:

> `k+��Hello, and welcome to the world o 39

However, by including the line, I am able to achieve the desired output:

> Hello, and welcome to the world of C++! 39

Comment: `char cstring[length];` is not supported by standard C++.

Comment: You don’t initialize the `cstring` to anything specific so its contents are whatever. Then you `strcat` into it, so it’ll find the first null in it and append the text. Initialize the array’s first element to zero.

Comment: Presumably `char cstring[length]` is not zero initialized, and `strcat` starts copying at the first null character in the existing string. But `char cstring[length]` is not standard C++, it is an extension. It shouldn't be taught to new C++ users. All in all, you should stop using c strings and stick to `std::string`. You should definitely **not** be teaching new users about c strings. It is not something that should be commonly used, it's hard to use correctly and mostly exists for backwards compatibility. It should be considered a more advance part of the language.

Comment: You should probably find a more modern source to learn C++ from. If it helps, anything before 2011 should be considered outdated.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'd go as far as ignore their existence completely. Barring certain legacy libraries that really just outlived their expected lifetime, for example OpenGL, most C API's should support functions of form `f(char const*, size_t);`, as in `f(s.c_str(), s.size());` is all you need to know, omitting size parameter is not any more complicated in case expected function is not available.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in those for loops, you **know** that `i` is a valid index, because you wrote it that way. You don't need to waste time checking it with `words.at(i)`. Just use `words[i]`.

Comment: Why are you complicating your life and using C API? Just concat strings using C++ `std::string` functionality or use `boost::join`

Answer (score 1):

For starters variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature

```
// Initialize the cstring to be of size length
char cstring[length];
```

Secondly you defined an uninitialized array. So using strcat invokes undefined behavior

```
strcat(cstring, (words.at(i) + " ").c_str());
```

This statement

```
// Null-terminate the cstring
cstring[length-1] = '\0';
```

is redundant because the function `strcat` appends also the terminating zero provided that the character array you declared has a space to accommodate the zero character (and you forgot to reserve a space for the terminating zero in the array).

If the compiler supports variable length arrays then the program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = 
    {
        "Hello,", "and", "welcome", "to", "the", "world", "of", "C++!"
    };
    
    // Calculate the total number of characters in the words vector 
    // (including an additional character for space)
    size_t length = words.size();

    for ( const auto &s : words ) length += s.length();
    
    // Initialize the cstring to be of size length
    char cstring[length + 1];
    cstring[0] = '\0';
    
    // Build the cstring using cstring library functions
    for ( const auto &s : words )
    {
        std::strcat( cstring, ( s + ' ' ).c_str() );
    }
    
    // Output the cstring
   std:: cout << cstring << ' ' << length << std::endl;
   
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello, and welcome to the world of C++!  40
```